# How to provision a windows box in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Maybe I am just not Googling for the right things, but I am not able to find a good example of a vagrantfile for Windows. I have written a Vagrantfile for linux, and have used shell provisioning for that situation. However, I am not able to find a good example of how to do this with windows. Can I do shell provisioning? Does it use batch scripting or power shell scripting?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how I missed this before when I was playing with it, but it says it during provisioning:

==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline PowerShell script

It does Powershell provisioning.